# Difference between turning off the Middleware and disabling it?

Tags: python, web-scraping, scrapy

For example, as far as I know, there is two ways of disabling `RedirectMiddleware`.

1. [In the `settings.py`, set `REDIRECT_ENABLED` to FALSE](http://doc.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/downloader-middleware.html#std:setting-REDIRECT_ENABLED)
2. [In the `settings.py`, modify the value of `scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.redirect.RedirectMiddleware` to `None` in the `DOWNLOADER_MIDDLEWARES_BASE`](http://doc.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/downloader-middleware.html#activating-a-downloader-middleware)

Is there any difference between the two?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a slight difference and it's mostly for convenience.

With `REDIRECT_ENABLED` you can adjust it in `spider.custom_settings` class argument. i.e.

```
class MySpider(scrapy.Spider):
    name = 'myspider'
    custom_settings = {'REDIRECT_ENABLED': True}
```

This way you can have `REDIRECT_ENABLED = False` project setting in `settings.py` and only enable it on certain spiders.
Alternative would be to set the whole `DOWNLOADER_MIDDLEWARES` in each spider in the `custom_settings` class argument which is significantly messier and I'm not sure if it would work at all.